# How to launch two applications with one keybinding in i3?

Tags: linux, i3

I am trying to come up with a command that will launch `cmus` in a terminal and `projectM-pulseaudio` right next to it (I am using i3 window manager).

When I try

```
projectM-pulseaudio && cmus
```

`cmus` does not start until I close ProjectM. And when I try

```
cmus && projectM-pulseaudio
```

Then ProjectM does not start until I quit `cmus`.

I understand that `cmus` is a command-line based tool while ProjectM isn't. I wanter if that's why it is not working or if there is anothe reason. Any thoughts?

Comment: @EightBitTony yes, run both applications at once. In i3, since it is a tiling window manager, two programs will share the screen exactly in the midline so I want `cmus` on the left side and ProjectM on the right side. Your command produces syntax error `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you type

```
utility1 && utility2
```

this means that `utility2` won't start until `utility1` have terminated with a zero exit status (but not otherwise).

Likewise,

```
utility1 || utility2
```

means that `utility2` will run if `utility1` terminates with a non-zero exit status (but not otherwise).

With

```
utility1 & utility2 &
```

which is the same as

```
utility1 &
utility2 &
```

you start both utilities as background processes (both will start independently of each other), and with

```
utility1 & utility2
```

which is the same as

```
utility1 &
utility2
```

you start `utility1` as a background process and then `utility2` as a foreground process.

This means, coincidentally, that the title of your question got it right:

```
cmus & projectM-pulseaudio
```

or possibly

```
projectM-pulseaudio & cmus
```

(but I don't know what these programs do, so I'm not not sure if it makes sense to run one or the other, or both, as a background process).

Comment: I see what you mean. Still, when I launch `cmus & projectM-pulseaudio` cmus doesn't start. Maybe the problem is that is a command-line based program, not a GUI. For example, `firefox & projectM-pulseaudio
` works just fine and opens both. If you don't have `cmus`, you can try any other command-line program.

Comment: @Oposum If `cmus` needs the input from the terminal, it can't run as a background job. Use `projectM-pulseaudio & cmus` instead.

Comment: tried it, cmus still doesn't start. I understand you may be infamiliar with these programs but you can try any other two programs, one command-line and another one with GUI.

Comment: You'll need to tell us what 'doesn't start' means and if there's any error message.

Comment: @Oposum With `xterm` (terminal emulator that opens its own window) and `mutt` (terminal-based email client), `xterm & mutt` "works", i.e. `xterm` opens its window and `mutt` starts in the terminal where I typed the command.

Comment: @Kusalananda got it, actually, it works after I add the `cmus` next to `xterm` like this: `xterm cmus & projectM-pulseaudio`

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to come up with a **command that will launch cmus in a terminal and projectM-pulseaudio right next to it (I am using i3 window manager).**

That's not the `i3` way. I think what you want is something like this,

```
bindsym $mod+v exec projectM-pulseaudio, exec kitty cmus
```

Note, you'll have to know how your terminal works. Though I suggest you use `kitty`, because it's easily the most feature bad ass terminal with ligature and graphic support -- it'll render pictures with Ranger on a framebuffer.

If you want a shell in addition to cmus (so when you're done it doesn't exit)

```
bindsym $mod+v exec projectM-pulseaudio, exec kitty bash -c'cmus'
```